# Result not expected in hex logical "and" with python

Tags: python, hex, long-integer

the next is part of a program I'm doing, I need to do an "AND" operation between 2 hexadecimal numbers, in the first part all is ok, but in the second part when I use an Hex number too long the result is different than I expected:

```
#this is ok
x = hex(268435456)       
transition = int(x, 16) & 0x000000FF 
>>>> print transition
>>>> 6

#this does not work
y = hex(268435456)
transition = int(y,16) & 0xFFFFFF00
>>>> print transition
>>>> 268435456
#in this case the result should be 10 00 00 00
```

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: '#in this case the result should be 10 00 00 00' why do you think that? And why are you converting numbers to hex strings and then back to int? They're already ints.

Comment: I can't reproduce the first result (I get 0).  The second result looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result **is** `0x10000000` hex, which is `268435456` in decimal. See `hex(268435456)`.

You don't need to convert your decimal numbers to strings and parse them back to ints. Just do:

```
x = 268435456
y = x
transition_x = x & 0xFF
transition_y = y & 0xFFFFFF00
print transition_x # 0
print transition_y # 268435456
```

Your first result is wrong. The result is `0`, not `6`.

If you define an integer number using decimal notation (`1234`), hexadecimal notation (`0x4d2`) or octal notation (`0o2322` or `02322`[py2]), it will always be stored as an `int` internally. The number literals I used above all represent the same decimal value of `1234`. Printing the number will always use decimal notation, unless you convert it explicitly to a certain string representation.

Comment: True, I didn't noticed that I need to convert the output to HEX to obtain the 0x10000000. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your result *is* `10 00 00 00`, you were just printing the decimal representation instead of the hexadecimal representation.

```
>>> print '{:x}'.format(268435456)
10000000
```

Comment: The result isn't. It is if you convert it to hex.

Comment: That's the hexadecimal representation (which is what the spacing every 2 digits implied).  It's the *same* integer, just represented 2 different ways